# List to two-dimensional Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How would one go about converting a list of integers to a two-dimensional array?

```
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
integerList.Add(1);
integerList.Add(2);
...
integerList.Add(250000);
int[,] integerArray = new int[500,500];

//fill integerArray with integerList values here
```

Target output should be in rows, filling x from 0-499 then incrementing y by 1 and repeat.
integerArray[x,y]

Comment: that would presumably depend upon how they are represented in the array, row order or column order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var number in integerList)
{
    integerArray[i % 500, (int)(i / 500)] = number;
    i++;
}
```

If you want to the number to increment through the column first, just transpose the mod and div operations inside the array.

Comment: If you want to the number to increment through the column first, just transpose the mod and div operations inside the array.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you @Michael Hays!

Comment: @Dani Done... thanks.  I seem to always find some nit with spelling or wording and end up editing these things constantly.  I read that if you did it too much, it became a wiki entry or some nonsense.  Still new here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list of arrays, but that won't guarantee the length of the items:

```
List l = new List<int[]>();
l.Add(new int[500]);
```